# Help win the Cat V Dog War

Tags: cipher

It's been a 100 days since the cat V dog war started today and two messenger planes have just collided both crashing down on war-torn land, one dog vessel, and one feline. Most letters were damaged irreparably on impact however two vital letters were recovered amidst the burning embers of war, one from the felines and one from the dogs. With either side having the other side's letter... Your the lead cryptologist for the cat's or the dogs, with the power to change the balance of the war drastically with the power of knowledge.

**The Ciphered Cat Letter reads**:

> Nete Spwrig, Wy uewitcs uwxk se wpi ifbgapnes ghoil, lx hroi h fnzzot gic l hhl. W yaws nqt fhv pb, nzh Z ubtm aqy. Pgo jwgsr dg ri ekpw wc fl? Ezr kayhk fa juwxl lds wcjl wnpz f qiox!? Z wqhm ewkovgr hvbwhma ozg vksvvyjrrg gulne, fhhkilt wgazhyqix, Z dmao lim ng ypng hiy eub vy pkbjk fahllb vw tcl. Yhv tspn V ihbrq qy. Vy xqmp hfyhx w sfqlxt oicgsg plai hux kozl hvh uuanx xu iar zh ycdp ng ktw. T xgn'e vvrk jai us skbjkr'p hywo zx tfzff xhjg ik pog zs nkbjk irsh vlpg lvwapwm naj e xzyh, dakvx aq jstx dewnww po fxi px pmvr mpphx jiev gna zxzm vj widbbnyc. Mcg wgc ubbbtw yvz pkjyozp, rfp tpng ka duop plo gva wvk'l zyssx owuese ew icgvlw Jvkkxmu Ugwhbtub. Nuxy eves fc yzfdiif jqamxoq!
>
> P.S. I used your name as the key, sorry, It's just easier to remember than the standard military key.

**The Ciphered Dog Letter reads:**

> Uc Osom, Ljy nnmwms sieprjm pwfpi lldr fwab wcxzhzh jr sht cullww iqjuenefifm tr Figvc Omgr. Acgmoxp vpblng zmy rfm nw ny waxhphxj. Cnw sc Zevgms'g frwuorl gwdc ghb ilv yxbsbof tgk qghr ee aovnqoeping oq ps. Jg vqxexogyv eqdiwzetxpb, jgf xkit wmol'u mtol hton rs fq bvxhlwncs'e jjvx's. T'gm prwy azrvqik Uemy gr fkwez bnbpzyansevm-ttxspzort omysbvrj mikd aafks jw kjx ygtrf yl mt hapg apdwt iaw pb'k czt nsoxlvz ybcw. Evs pmyotsg ktci xiyb n ggcemx gtrkavwqi kh wcjcimzvxx cce glax, nhh'w rcjdoninlr lkm dqqvxzsq hm xss uuimf jsfivr, obn avni wt ggqwgz iesqkz mi iplrx o wga pcnsl uolr ul zszpda lth ioq onrd. Ebkcwhl rm jdd ekvtpb pr wclswy esgil tcdqbt t pxljxt pwe unf iq zyk kwesfx. Afmvv mm qmv lqe rii avxbk ar xal igu? Ntpt ztuekrg mo tzat uis eqw rtgqhcmdeq d pih nsvhzrj ta Kxexy Fqge owk cgwctokmpvd nhqrvrj tlbp mbr oilum. Zh ihu'x ci eczg mdsl'em tvotyusc flgt toqacwc keaipst dphr wljvr, tyw wp yhvoj pjex batg akq mm yyk imkf cfbrqy kp lam voe xkxmsu eaxyi sb vhyapz!
>
> -Incase you forgot the key is "cnodchtbvhu"

**Hints:**

Cats

> read the end of the letter

Dogs

> read the end of the letter

Comment: The puzzle would've been more challenging if the hints were actual hints, not solutions to the ciphers. E.g. a hint for the dog-key could've been *"alternating"*, although that wouldn't really be necessary here. Most people who try to solve an unsolved puzzle here always look at the hints straight away, since they want to be the first to answer. You can also try to wait a while before adding hints to your next puzzle and see if it gets solved without them.

Comment: @LukasRotter point taken.

Comment: Dogs: NONONONONO!!! WHY GIVE THE KEY IN THE MESSAGE!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cats

> (Vigenere Autokey "katnip")
> Dear Katnip, My brother died on the frontline today, he took a bullet for a dog. I hate him for it, but I miss him. How could he do this to me? Why would he value his life over a mutt!? I went looking through his belongings today, nothing intrusive, I just had to find out why he would betray us all. And then I found it. He knew about a secret weapon that the dogs are going to use to kill us all. I don't know why he wouldn't tell me about this or why he would even kill himself for a mutt, maybe he just wanted to see me burn along with the rest of felinity. But one things for certain, now that we know the the dog's super weapon is inside Biscuit Mountain. They will be crushed swiftly!

Dogs

> (Vigenere Autokey "bonebiscuit"; "cnodchtbvhu" = alternating ROT-1 and ROT-25 ciphers.)
> To Bone, The futile felines would have been crushed in our latest advancement to Kitty City. However things did not go as expected. One of Katnip's snipers took out the general and made an advancement on us. We retreated immediately, but that didn't save half of my batallion's live's. I've been sending Tail on short intelligence-gathering missions ever since we got holed up in this place and it's not looking good. The felines have sent a covert operative to inflitrate our base, who's discovered the location of the super weapon, why were we stupid enough to think a cat would help us defeat his own kind. Luckily he was killed in action today taking a bullet for one of our finest. Maybe he did see the truth in the end? Tail managed to loot him and discovered a map leading to Kitty City via underground tunnels from the beach. It won't be easy they'll probably have capable defense down there, but it looks like this may be our best chance to hit the kitten where it counts!